# Is it healthy to eat cereal-like food instead of rice or pasta each meal five days a week?

Tags: food

The pantry in my workplace has various kinds of cereal-like food, which might contain some dry berries or bran or ..., and look good. 
It doesn’t offer beans, pasta or rice.

I know cereal-like food is usually eaten as breakfast. So I wonder if it is healthy to eat cereal-like food instead of beans, pasta or rice for three meals a day, for 5 days each week?

p.s. The pantry has no salad, but fresh carrot, celery, blueberry, black raspberry, strawberry, banana, apple, and orange. It also has eggs, yogurt, cheese, bars of mixed nuts. I base my three meals a day on the pantry.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions about nutrition are off-topic. But the answer is "probably no". You haven't mentioned protein at all in that diet. You can replace your carbohydrate intake with cereal as always, a varied diet is best.

Comment: The pantry has eggs, yogurt, and cheese, and I eat them.  I guess they provide the protein you point out.

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially all carbs and no good fats/protein.

So no, that will not be healthy.

Comment: I also eat  eggs, yogurt, and cheese in the pantry everyday.

Comment: Can you elaborate? This is not really a good standard for an answer, a couple of tossed of lines with no support.

Comment: Elaborate? The question was: Is it healthy to eat breakfast food all day every day that has a macro level of C/P/F of something like 70/10/20... The answer is simple: No, it is not healthy.